# layout and image display in android

Tags: android, image, layout, resources

I am writing my application which is highly based on images and I have to be care full while designing GUI for manyyyyy different devices.

I have started reading different resources specially http://developer.android.com . I want to discuss some points which are not clear for me.

1. Supporting Different Screens

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Android says that use different layouts for different screen sizes

for example

MyProject/

res/

layout/main.xml

layout-land/main.xml

layout-large/main.xml

layout-large-land/main.xml
My Question is if I have layout with 2 edit boxes 1 check box and 2 buttons,

Why should I use 3 copies of xml file in land, large and land-large (land-medium or if more) layout.

1. Create Different Bitmaps

My second question is about Images which is more important,

Which image size I should use,

MyProject/

res/

drawable-xhdpi/awesomeimage.png

drawable-hdpi/awesomeimage.png

drawable-mdpi/awesomeimage.png

drawable-ldpi/awesomeimage.png

in ldpi folder I put 150*150 px picture and when I run in on 3.7 screen size then this picture quality is really bad and blur in 150*150 size image view. But if I put 700*700 px in same folder then image view displays sharp results in 150*150 size.

Why not I put 700*700 picture in one folder and display it in different image views, this why i can utilize one resource for many purposes.

Comment: Google engineers have simply helped with such provisions. Keeping separate layouts for different size of screens is just to have a dynamic and precise control. Android has varied range of handsets with variable range of resolution and dimensions. having different image resources are necessary, as it gives you the required details on relevant dpi screens. Android documentation has fair explanation along with illustrations. Investing a bit of your time will really help, as i feel they have explained well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define bitmaps of whatever size you want and put them in your `res/drawable` folder. The your layout can reference that single image. If you add it to an ImageView, use the image view properties to control how the images scale to fit inside the image view.

For example create folders and files like this:

```
res/drawable
    image_700x700.png
res/layout
    layout.xml
```

If you want to use drawable-xdpi, drawable-hdpi, ect you are free to do so. Those folders are used to provide different size images for different screen pixel densities. For example look at the app icon that android generates for a new android project. You will find that each folder has similar images of different sizes. If you only have one image of 700x700 then you only put that image in the folder called "drawable". If you want you can generate several different images that are different sizes and will show on different screen densities. If you do this you want to make all the images but the same number of DP.

Comment: Nathan... ifyou can eloborate this point more.....about me last 5 lines.. if i have picture which is 700 by 700px.... what should i do... should i put this file in all drawable folders...?

Comment: Nathan now you are getting my point. Now if i have following folders   
drawable-xhdpi/
drawable-hdpi/
drawable-mdpi/
drawable-ldpi/
Now tell me should i put image_700x700 in every folder

Comment: You can add a new folder called "drawable" your are not limited to just the one you currently have. I can't tell you for sure what to do. I provided more info to help you decide which way is best your your case.